# Is "abc" + 5 considered an expression in python?

Tags: python, software-design

Since a expression in python is defined as "a combination of values, variables, and operators that evaluates to a single value".

If we take something like "abc" + 5. though it is a combination of values, variable and operators it doesn't evaluate to a single value ,it would give an error since you cannot add a string with a integer.

So would it be considered an expression why or why not?

Comment: It's your definition. So you tell us.

Comment: If I strung a random sequence of words together, is it a sentence? You already know it throws an error, so what difference would this distinction make?

Comment: @roganjosh Now that would be something I'd like to see. I doubt that, and I'd learn something about the grammar.

Comment: @KellyBundy man you're hard to shake off :P Ok, if it's not "grammar", then can you accept that there's no type coercion here and that it's just fundamentally broken? Without type coercion, which JS might give, this is just a non-issue

Comment: @roganjosh Hmm, I try to always be accurate myself, often looking up definitions of words before using them so I don't misuse them. I doubt I'll ever have a use for this, but somehow it does intrigue me. (And now I just looked up "intrigue" to be sure it means what I think it means :-)

Comment: @KellyBundy FWIW I appreciate you holding me to account. Don't stop. Bottom line from me - "is 'abc' + 5 considered an expression in python?" - No. It's an error. End of discussion? We just got drawn in...

Comment: Tbh just a question out of curiosity not that this distinction would matter in any scenario.

Comment: I think it's a fair question; you can see how it's animated the community :)

Comment: @roganjosh I agree there is no debate. It is an expression. :)

Comment: I have taken this definition from an NCERT textbook [link](https://ncert.nic.in/textbook/pdf/keip103.pdf)
you can find it on the bottom of page 11, certainly not a reliable source hence this question looking for a better definition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is absolutely an expression. Others have linked to the official language reference, but if that doesn't suit you, you can ask the CPython parser itself, the *an authority on what constitutes a Python expression*:

```
>>> import ast
>>> print(ast.dump(ast.parse('"abc" + 5'), indent=2))
Module(
  body=[
    Expr(
      value=BinOp(
        left=Constant(value='abc'),
        op=Add(),
        right=Constant(value=5)))],
  type_ignores=[])
```

It is an expression that will always result in an exception being raised. But that is netiher here nor there.

Consider the following function:

```
import random

def foo():
    if random.random() >= 0.5:
        raise RuntimeError("Nah ah ah!")
```

Well, then, I hope we can all agree that:

```
foo()
```

Is an expression. Even though sometimes it will raise an error. Otherwise, would have to say "we don't know if that is an expression or not until it is called."

No. It is an expression. An expression that can raise a runtime error. Like many other expressions.

Here is a good operational definition for an expression in Python. An expression in Python is anything that can go on the right-hand side of a simple assignment statement:

```
x = <some expression>
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, by any reasonable definition. I'll argue this, both from your definition and from the one I would use.

According to your definition,

> a expression in python is defined as "a combination of values, variables, and operators that evaluates to a single value".

I disagree with this, because it excludes literally everything. Your exception problem isn't unique to that example. `a + b` can *never* be an expression because `a` might be a class whose `__add__` just throws. So I would, more precisely, say

> An expression is a term in Python that evaluates to a single value or throws an exception

And that solves your problem.

But I still wouldn't use that definition. See, when we're talking about expressions, we're usually talking about syntax and parsing, and you're getting bogged down in the semantics of the runtime with your definition. Usually, we define an "expression" inductively. That is, we start with a few basic expressions (This is not a complete list, just some examples):

- Every integer literal is an expression.
- The special constant `None` is an expression.
- A string literal enclosed in quotes is an expression.

Then we build up compound expressions inductively through conditionals.

- If `a` and `b` are arbitrary expressions, then so is `a + b`.
- If `f` and `a1, a2, ... an` are expressions, then so is `f(a1, a2, ... an)`.
- If `a1, a2, ... an` are expressions, then so is `[a1, a2, ... an]`.

Such a definition ends up being largely technical, and the exact details are available publicly with the [Python grammar](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html). But again, that's *really* technical stuff, and you don't really need to know it unless you're hacking on the Python compiler itself.

Answer (score 2):

I can't find an official source for that definition. [Here's](https://runestone.academy/ns/books/published/thinkcspy/SimplePythonData/StatementsandExpressions.html) someone using it to explain Python, but [here's](https://www.prepbytes.com/blog/javascript/javascript-operators/) someone using the exact same words to explain Javascript.

The [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html) don't have such language when describing an expression.

And yes, `"abc"+5` must be an expression, because "expression" is a term for a part of Python's grammar. It concerns values during parsing, regardless of their runtime behavior.

Comment: While you might be able to make this work in JS, it will blow up in Python. How is something that throws an error an "expression" any more than the keys my cat would type walking across the keyboard?

Comment: There's of course the [glossary entry](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-expression), which at least says something similar. But I stick with my point that the OP should show us their source before we start answering.

Comment: @KellyBundy I think this is a mind trap for people to debate the philosophy of the question. It _doesn't work_ so what are we even debating? It's not an expression - it's an error

Comment: @roganjosh Am I debating? I just tried to pull the source out of the OP and I won't get into this before I can read it there myself and what else is said there. Only provided a link here because of BoppreH's second paragraph, and stated my belief that we shouldn't answer before the OP provided the info.

Comment: @KellyBundy apologies, I didn't mean to direct at you specifically. The answer is simple and I commented on the question as such. There is no debate to be had here

Comment: @roganjosh whether something is an *expression* or a *statement* is a matter of *grammar*. It is a matter of *syntax*. `"abc" + 5` is an expression because doing `x = "abc" + 5` will not raise a `SyntaxError` when the source code is parsed/compiled. That it happens to raise a runtime error is irrelevant.

Comment: @KellyBundy I have taken this definition from an NCERT textbook [link](https://ncert.nic.in/textbook/pdf/keip103.pdf)
you can find it on the bottom of page 11, certainly not a reliable source hence this question looking for a better definition.